# Markers ignored when using Plot.extend()

Tags: python, plot, sympy

With this code:

```
from sympy import symbols, plot, sin, pi
from numpy import linspace

x = symbols('x')
s = linspace(-2 ,10, 3)

def plot_one(a):
    return plot(sin(2*x) / x + x + a, (x, -2*pi, 2*pi),
                markers=[{'args': (0, a, 'ro')}], show=False)

plots = None
for v in s:
    one_plot = plot_one(v)
    if plots: plots.extend(one_plot)
    else: plots = one_plot

plots.aspect_ratio = (1, 1)
plots.show()
```

markers created by the function are ignored except the first one:

[image]

I can imagine a solution merging the markers manually and using `markers` keyword only in a final call, but is there a more simple way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `markers` is not taken into consideration by the `extend` method. One way to solve the problem is to attach all the markers to the first plot:

```py
from sympy import symbols, plot, sin, pi
from numpy import linspace

x = symbols('x')
s = linspace(-2 ,10, 3)

def plot_one(a):
    return plot(sin(2*x) / x + x + a, (x, -2*pi, 2*pi), show=False)

markers = [{"args": (0, a, 'ro')} for a in s]
p0 = plot_one(s[0])
p0.markers = markers

for i in range(1, len(s)):
    p0.extend(plot_one(s[i]))

p0.aspect_ratio = (1, 1)
p0.show()
```

[image]